# Tkinter default font is tiny

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using some libraries that are using tkinter, and the font is so tiny I can't read it (a few pixels only). Here is a minimum working example:

```
from tkinter import *                                                                                                                           
root = Tk()
myLabel = Label(root, text = 'Hello, world!')
myLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The working example produces the tiny hello world in the window to the right: [mwe tiny font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crrql.png)
The rest of the image is showing the gitk gui as a size reference.

Is there a way to set the default font size in tkinter without changing the code? It could also be a problem with dpi settings?

I am on Arch linux, i3wm, using the nvidia proprietary driver

Comment: When you say "without changing the code", do you mean that literally? Is it acceptable if the solution requires adding just one or two lines of code?

Comment: Yes, I literally mean "without changing the code", because this is some tkinter based application I install through a package manager. There must be some system from where tkinter picks up the default font on linux. Perhaps fontconfig? But I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to my problem.
Tkinter has an automatic way to determine the monitor size and it will set a tk scale variable accordingly. In my case the scaling value does the opposite of what it is supposed to do - larger scaling value leads to smaller font size. I still don't know why that is the case.
I ran strace on my minimum working example and found out that tkinter tries to read the file `~/.Tk.tcl` and I can therefore use this file as a configuration file.
Putting `tk scaling 1.0` into `~/.Tk.tcl` solved the problem for me. You can experiment with the scaling value to increase/decrease the overall scaling of the gui components.
Looking at strace it also tries to read `~/.Tk.py`, `~/.example.tcl` and `~/.example.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the beginning of your code. change `helevicta` by the font you want to use, change `20` by the font size you want to use and change `bold` by any formatting options you want (you don't have to include any, and if you do, you can add more than one.) This line will set the font for any labels in the `root` window.

```
root.option_add("*Label.Font", "helvetica 20 bold")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set default font for tkinter widgets. Refer to this thread

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462647/modify-the-default-font-in-python-tkinter#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=Tkinter%20has%20several%20built%2Din,them%20will%20change%20as%20well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462647/modify-the-default-font-in-python-tkinter#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Tkinter%20has%20several%20built%2Din,them%20will%20change%20as%20well).